# default_url method of carrierwave doesn't work with me

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, default, carrierwave

I have a problem with default_url method in Carrierwave as it doesn't work.
My code looks like this

```
      class ImageFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

      include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

      storage :file
      def store_dir
          "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end
      version :small do
        process :resize_to_fill => [75, 75]
      end
      version :thumb do
        process :resize_to_fill => [120, 120]
      end
      version :medium do
        process :resize_to_fill => [639, 426]
      end
      def extension_white_list
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
      end
      version :thumb_default_avatar do
         process :resize_to_fill => [120, 120]
      end
      def default_url
        ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [thumb_default_avatar.jpg,  
        "default_avatar.jpg"].compact.join('_'))
      end
      end
```

and I have this model which I need to set its avatar with the default_avatar image

```
    class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
      mount_uploader :avatar, ImageFileUploader 
    end
```

Also I created a "fallback" folder included the default_avatar.jpg image in the "public" folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know its not working? How did you test it? Also, where have you stored the fallback image `default_avatar.jpg`?

Comment: @KirtiThorat I edited my question so kindly review it, and I known that its not working because when I created a new Agent and not chosen an image for that Agent, Nothing occurs (No default image uploaded).

Comment: Read the UPDATE 2 in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine with me, when I changed the default_url method as shown

```
    def default_url
      /fallback/default_avatar.jpg'
    end
```

Thanks @Kirti Thorat, I understood your explanation about saving in DB.

Answer (score 0):

For `default_url` method to work, you would have to place the version specific default images i.e., `small_default_avatar.jpg`, `thumb_default_avatar.jpg` and `medium_default_avatar.jpg` in `public/fallback`(Note within **public**) folder. So, when you don't upload an image for a record then the `CarrierWave` would display the image from `default_url` instead of showing the broken image icon.

**UPDATE**

As per the code shared for `ImageFileUploader`, you are creating **4 versions of whatever image you upload** namely `:small`, `:thumb`, `:medium` and `:thumb_default_avatar`. That's why, logically you should place version specific default images in the `public/fallback` folder. So, for example in your Agent show view if you are trying to render image with version `:small` and image was not uploaded while Agent creation then instead of showing broken image the default image for version `:small` i.e., `small_default_avatar.jpg` would be picked up to be displayed.

**UPDATE 2**

Default urls are not saved in the database. At runtime, `CarrierWave` checks whether or not an image was uploaded for an Agent. If image was uploaded it displays the image from stored directory and if image was not uploaded it directly displays the default image. So, no you are not supposed to store default url's in the database.

Comment: " you would have to place the version specific default images " I didn't understand what you mean, Could you clarify your answer :)

Comment: Read the UPDATE section in my answer.